# What is the proper way of scanning a bunch of monero private keys to get an updated balance?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc, privatekey, block-scanning

I have a database of monero private keys, but I want to be able to scan these keys for an updated balance and insert this balance data back into my database.

What is the best way to rescan a bunch of monero private keys? Do I use moner-wallet-cli or the rpc command? Is there an example somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `monero-wallet-rpc` https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html.

You would use the methods `open_wallet`, `refresh` and `get_balance`.